# How to use Doxygen with Prolog

Tags: c, prolog, doxygen

I was struggling trying to make `doxygen` work with `prolog`.

At first I was only trying to include an "external and unknown" file, but as doxygen users know, it won't print a thing if it can't find useful (documented) functions.

Searching stackoverflow for both tags gives no single answer, and so I decided to ask, even if I already solved the puzzle, so people will have a hit in case of search.

I will let this question here, as people can suggest simple workarounds, and we may learn a bit more about the subject, but I'll use it to register my own answer after some (hard) efforts. Thanks.

---

To explain where I did start:

My first (almost) successful approach worked fine in a program that used both `C` and `PROLOG`.

It almost worked because latter on I saw this approach would not work in a `PROLOG` only project.

Anyway, what I did was simply add this

```
INPUT = README.md groups.dox c-and-pl.c c-and-pl.pl
FILE_PATTERNS = *.pl
EXTENSION_MAPPING += pl=c
EXTRACT_ALL = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC = YES
SOURCE_BROWSER = YES
```

And `PROLOG` code would look like:

```
/**
 * @file cpl.pl
 * @ingroup GroupUnique
 * @brief CPL - C calls Prolog (Prolog module)
 * @cond SKIPPROLOG
 */

 /* brief explanation in a normal (non-doxygen) comment */
 clause(A) :- 
     rule(X),
     test(A, X).

 and(so, on).

 /** @endcond */
```

This would work because `C` would create the site anyway, and `PROLOG` page would be just a brief, no clauses, but a link to see the complete code, with normal comments explaining the clauses.

Why this doesn't work for a pure `PROLOG` project? And how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My second attempt to solve it involved the creation of a new file, a copy of the original `PROLOG` source, but with comments in `doxygen` format, and converting `PROLOG` clauses in something `C-like`.

Call the source `source.pl` and the second copy `source.dox`. You would write the `PROLOG` program as you usually do, using `doxygen` before the first occurrence of each clause, atom, module, etc.

Then `cp source.pl source.dox` and edit `source.dox` converting all clauses in something like:

```
/**
 * \file source.pl
 * \ingroup GroupUnique
 */

/**
 * \ingroup GroupUnique
 * \brief Defining factorial module
 */
module(fatorial, [fatpl/2]);
```

This takes time and are prone to errors, but it was a workaround. Problem is that `doxygen` now lists `source.pl` twice. But the functions can be documented. Use this configuration:

INPUT = README.md groups.dox source.pl source.dox

You need to keep `source.pl` because it is there the real source to be seen. And `source.dox` would be more like a `C header file`.

---

Not good. The work to transform manually a `source.pl` into a `source.dox` led me to write my own compiler (well, technically a `filter`, that uses only lexical tokens).

The program is available open source at github:

https://github.com/drbeco/doxygenprolog

and is cited here in the official pages among other filters: [doxygen helpers](http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html)

And a little note here, in the official SWI-Prolog site:
[SWI-Prolog news](http://www.swi-prolog.org/news/3b9546ec-1d66-11e5-9067-00163e357fe2)

To make doxygen work with an unknown language you need:

- Install this filter in someplace `PATH` can find.
- Edit your doxygen `.cfg` to have:

  > OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C = NO
  >
  > INPUT = README.md groups.dox source.pl
  >
  > EXTRACT_ALL = YES
  >
  > EXTRACT_STATIC = YES
  >
  > FILE_PATTERNS = *.pl *.prolog *.swipl
  >
  > FILTER_PATTERNS = *.pl="dox4pl"
- Now you can run your `doxygen` as you normally do with other languages.